Where in the world does GPS time proceed at one second per second? Is there a map?
The definition, measurement, and distribution of what time it is is a complicated thing, and only certain sturdy folks have the patience to understand it really and fully.
It suddenly dawned on me that GPS time (for example) is a purely artificial construct. Zillions of things on Earth depend on it to varying levels of precision. I think the internet and cellular data does, the Event Horizon Telescope interferometry does.
But each receiver reconstructs GPS time from several Doppler-shifted signals from things flying overhead constantly changing distance. GPS time doesn't exist until someone turns on a radio + computer and reconstructs it.
Yes folks will argue that GPS time is synchronized to terrestrial atomic clocks, but don't spoil my epiphany - if we blow up all of those clocks, GPS time will keep going.
Anyway. Suppose I have a really, really good but portable atomic clock and a GPS clock and a box that subtracts the two. If I go up on a mountain or visit the dead sea, I can get the difference to behave differently. Same with going fast or staying still, or moving from pole to equator.
Question: So I wonder; where in the world does GPS time proceed at one second per second?
Auxiliary questions to indicate the scope of the answer I'm hopeing is possible:

Is there a map?
Is it two wobbly 1-dimensional rings at +/- 40 degrees latitude, trying to stay near zero GPS elevation?
Is it one or more 2-dimensional surfaces?
How high above Earth's surface does it reach in places?
How far below ground?


Very interesting question. I doubt the surface/rings in question have any relationship to the "altitude" WRT Earth's surface. Imagine GPS satellites were orbiting around a black hole of one earth mass.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I didn't think there was such a thing as "zero GPS altitude".  I thought GPS provided a 3D fix, then the altitude was calculated by subtracting the assumed geoid from that fix ???

How would anybody be able to tell what 1 second per second meant or be able to measure it let alone map it.

@Slarty You compare a precise clock to GPS time. They will not, in general, "tick" at the same rate.

GPS time drifts without regular adjustments to each satellite - if we blow up the clocks on Earth they will all start drifting off from each other.

@JonCuster Yes, over time those space-based atomic clocks will slowly drift and at some point the whole system will stop working. I suppose that will take days or weeks? I'm not denying that they need regular maintenance and tlc, but it's not like they would shut down instantly.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/271900/how-do-gps-satellites-refresh-their-clocks has some interesting info for those interested…

Except for zero epoch definitions, GPS time is an extrapolation of TAI, which is a realization of TT. TT is defined to "tick" at 1 SI second on the geoid (the redshift is theoretically the same everywhere on the geoid). Thus, with the caveats applicable to any extrapolated measurement, GPS seconds match SI seconds at zero altitude on Earth.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

GPS time is by definition TAI + 19 seconds. So we can just look at TAI instead of GPS.
TAI increases by definition by one second every second. Due to relativity a nuclear clock in motion or at some height will not run at that speed, so TAI is measured by averaging a large number of nuclear clocks.
Now you can ask “at which points of the Earth would a very precise nuclear clock agree precisely with TAI”. The speed is affected by its speed which we can determine from its location (easy if you don’t want much precision, for more precision we must take int account that earth is an imperfect geoid) and the gravity at its location (again we can determine this easily with los precision by just taking the height above sea level, and more precisely by taking the precise shape of the earth and the distribution of lighter and heavier materials into account)
In principle we could create a map which shows for every pair of latitude/longitude at which height above sea level time dilation will be constant.

"Due to relativity a nuclear clock in motion or at some height will not run at that speed, so TAI is measured by averaging a large number of nuclear clocks.": This implies that times reported by clocks to TAI are not corrected for altitude, but they have been since 1977. Also they're atomic clocks, not nuclear clocks.

Behold, the relativistic geoid!

The Relativistic Geoid: Gravity Potential and Relativistic Effects (also here)
Definition of the relativistic geoid in terms of isochronometric surfaces (also here)
Relativistic geoids and time dependence: quasilocal frames versus isochronometric surfaces


The following sentence describes surface I'm asking about: “The relativistic geoid is the surface where precise clocks run with the same speed and the surface is nearest to mean sea level."
There can be many surfaces where they run at the same speed, one can then choose the one that most closely follows the geoid, and use that.
As discussed below, while I don't yet understand why a hydrostatic equilibrium surface so nearly-but-not-quite perfectly solves a special + general relativity problem (to order few × 10-19!) it seems it does manage to do that. I'm guessing it's because Earth's gravity is relatively (see what I did there?) weak, and so the hydrostatic solution somehow matches the leading terms in some expansion of the general problem.
Answers should be supported by good sources.
I found this particularly helpful as it explicitly addresses how fast clocks tick at geoids.
From Mehlstäubler, Grosche, Lisdat, Schmidt, and Denker (2018) "Atomic Clocks for Geodesy" https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.01585

2.5 Clocks for establishing physical height reference systems
... Furthermore, Bjerhammar (1985) also gave the following remarkable definition for the geoid, stating that “The relativistic geoid is the surface where precise clocks run with the same speed and the surface is nearest to mean sea level”. In this context, a comparison of equations (2.26) and (2.7) shows that the (classical) definition of the geoid as an equipotential surface is, to the level of approximation used above (roughly a few parts in 1019), identical with a surface on which clocks tick with the same rate. However, with the advent of optical clocks with below the level of 10-18 and corresponding links for their remote comparison, proposals for a new definition of a relativistic geoid based on optical clocks have become more and more realistic (Kopeikin et al. 2011; Müller et al. 2017; Phillip et al. 2017).

Annotations added.


Figure 2.2: Geoid and level surfaces, quasigeoid, ellipsoid, heights, continental topography, mean sea level (MSL), dynamic ocean topography (DOT), and sea surface height (SSH). The principle of chronometric levelling is indicated by the clock symbols and the spiral-shaped lines for the link technologies (for further details see Sect. 2.5).



Is there a map?

For practical purposes, yes as other answers suggest, the conventional geoid would be the map.


Is it one or more 2-dimensional surfaces?
How high above Earth's surface does it reach in places?
How far below ground?


I suppose I will have to answer these myself. A quick search didn't find a subtraction of the Earth's surface from the geoid. I have the Earth's surface from this answer to Seeking topographical data for northern Taiwan to make sense of peak-to-peak photos in 3D? and I assume I can find a Python library to evaluate the spherical harmonic expansion coefficients of the geoid.
Stay tuned...

I can't tell the difference between the relativistic geoid and the Newtonian geoid. They say the relativistic geoid coincides with the results of local plumb lines, but I feel like the Newtonian geoid also coincides with those results..

@Jagerber48 the problem is a mathematical one, not necessarily amenable to prose. So compare equations (2.26) and (2.7) as the block quote points out, or check some of the other references linked in the beginning. I may post a new question about the "close, but no cigar" relationship between the hydrostatic equilibrium and the iso-tick GR surfaces. If/when I do I'll ping you back here.

To answer your last three questions: I think it's clear it's one 2D surface. Isn't a standard topographic map all that you are looking for? These maps show elevation of the local ground above sea level, which I take to mean the geoid. The highest point above the Geoid is mount Everest, ~8.85 km above sea level and the lowest is the dead sea, ~400 m below sea level.

Are you sure these papers are suggesting that (there is a difference between a geoid defined based on the shape of a body of water and the geoid defined using clocks) and not simply (that clocks will provide more accurate measurements of the geoid that the historical surveying/tide gauge based approaches)?

The classical definition of the geoid seems to be a relativistic potential isosurface (this is the shape water would take if undisturbed by winds or tides) closest to mean sea level. This is indeed a different definition than the surface where clocks tick at the same speed closest to sea level. But I'm not aware of (even after skimming/reading the references) of any physical effect that suggest these two definitions would yield different surfaces.

@Jagerber48 to each their own I guess.

This concept appears to be worse than worthless, which is why the linked articles are cross referenced at a very low rate and, as far as I can tell, is not used. To make matters even worse, most of the very few cross references that do exist appear to by coauthors writing elsewhere, or a cohort in league with the coauthors.

This relativistic geoid concept ignores the Earth's non-spherical shape and also ignores tidal effects. Worse than worthless.

@DavidHammen If a proposed relativist geoid deviates by only 10${}^{-19}$ from the current accepted geoid, then I don't see how "...ignores the Earth's non-spherical shape..." could possibly be true.  Can you point to a specific place in a specific paper where we can see this ignoring happening? Are you just assuming they ignored it without verifying? I mean, Phys. Rev. D. is a reasonable journal with editors and peer review...

@DavidHammen and wouldn't a much more likely lack of citations be that it's simply not interesting because at only $10{}^{-19}$ it's simply not important to think about currently?

@DavidHammen  How can you blame (iiuc) the relativistic geoid concept for "ignoring" the shape of the geoid when it actually analytically produces it (as it must, since it is a relativistic equipotential surface calculation in a rotating system)?

I think these references are being misinterpreted. I think they are saying that a clock-based geoid would agree exactly with a plumb line based geoid. The plumb-line geoid coincides with the "static body of water" geoid. The references draw distinctions between Newtonian and relativistic geoids. But I think this is just pointing out something like if you try to predict the geoid from the mass distribution of Earth you will be incorrect if you use a Newtonian, or even post-Newtonian theory (basically Newtonian + low order relativistic corrections). Instead the references detail how

you can apply a fully relativistic model to prediction of the shape of the geoid. But, as an experimentalist, I'm not really interested in a theoretical prediction for the shape of the geoid. I'm interested in how we can measure the geoid. The answer is that we can measure it with plumb lines (which would include looking at the shape of the ocean, assuming it is homogeneous) or with clocks. The articles all suggests that in the future clocks might be a more accurate way to measure the geoid. Great!

So I take issue with the claim that there are two different geoids, one based on clocks, and one not based on clocks, that differ at ~10^-19 level. I don't think that is what is being claimed by the references.

Though I do have to admit I'm still wrestling with the quoted section 2.5 that is quoted in this answer.
